# iPhone X tool bar issue at the bottom

Tags: ios, storyboard, iphone-x

My app works well on all device except for iPhone X.

On iPhone X the tool bar on the bottom is shown like as shown in image
[image: showing like this]

But I want to show it like shown in second image 
[image: want to show like this]

But when ever I shift the tool bar up so that it will show properly on iPhone X then it also move upwards in other devices.

How should I solve this problem.

Comment: There is a safe area layout in iphone x so it will only effect when running in iphone x and in other device it will be same. Please search about safe area layout

Comment: Thanks a lot @Jitender.

Comment: i was able to achieve this with safe are layout.

Comment: welcome, it's my pleasure @parv bhaskar

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually the bottom bar of my view is inside another view thats why it is not extending accordingly.

So simply putting the bottom bar outside, on the main view and adjusting the constraint simply resolve my issue.

Answer (score 0):

In my case My toolbar's bottom constraint was attached to superview's bottom. Changing it to Safe Area bottom resolved the issue for me